# How to reload class in spring boot classloader?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classloader, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

There is situation where I need to update class binaries without restarting spring boot application. I know there are ways for creating a new class Loader each time when new binaries are required to load. That approach works perfectly in simple java application. Any suggestion?

I created new classloader by extending Classloader class and read class file. I tried basic approach to load binary with new classloader in spring boot application. but it didn't work. I want application load new binary of class without restarting server.